# how to write the user inputted values into the csv file or excel file in html page

Tags: javascript, html

How can i export the values of the text box in html to a csv or a excel 
.I have created an HTML Form which will be used from a local computer and want the form data to be saved in CSV file.

Each time the form is submitted, it should add a line in the CSV file.

This needs to be run locally so cannot use PHP or JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file handling technique through java script to write .csv file

```
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 // 2=overwrite, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
 varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\myfile.csv", 2, true,0);
 varFileObject.write("File handling in Javascript");
 varFileObject.close();
```

for more information about how to use file handling in Javascript visit [code project site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18869/File-Handling-at-Client-Side-Using-Javascript)

Comment: Can i do it without activeX ...as i would like the HTML to run on a android device.